# Extending auto-generated Amplify Datastore classes with factory constructors

Tags: flutter, dart, class, inheritance, aws-amplify

The base model generated through AWS Amplify Studio:

```dart
@immutable
class Patient extends Model {
  static const classType = const _PatientModelType();
  final String id;
  final String? _name;
  final String? _family_name;
  final TemporalDate? _dob;
  final Gender? _gender;
  final double? _height_in_inches;
  final List<Assessment>? _Assessments;
  final TemporalDateTime? _createdAt;
  final TemporalDateTime? _updatedAt;

 ...
  
  const Patient._internal({required this.id, required name, required family_name, required dob, required gender, required height_in_inches, Assessments, createdAt, updatedAt}): _name = name, _family_name = family_name, _dob = dob, _gender = gender, _height_in_inches = height_in_inches, _Assessments = Assessments, _createdAt = createdAt, _updatedAt = updatedAt;
  
  factory Patient({String? id, required String name, required String family_name, required TemporalDate dob, required Gender gender, required double height_in_inches, List<Assessment>? Assessments}) {
    return Patient._internal(
      id: id == null ? UUID.getUUID() : id,
      name: name,
      family_name: family_name,
      dob: dob,
      gender: gender,
      height_in_inches: height_in_inches,
      Assessments: Assessments != null ? List<Assessment>.unmodifiable(Assessments) : Assessments);
  }
  
  ...
  
  Patient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)  
    : id = json['id'],
      _name = json['name'],
      _family_name = json['family_name'],
      _dob = json['dob'] != null ? TemporalDate.fromString(json['dob']) : null,
      _gender = enumFromString<Gender>(json['gender'], Gender.values),
      _height_in_inches = (json['height_in_inches'] as num?)?.toDouble(),
      _Assessments = json['Assessments'] is List
        ? (json['Assessments'] as List)
          .where((e) => e?['serializedData'] != null)
          .map((e) => Assessment.fromJson(new Map<String, dynamic>.from(e['serializedData'])))
          .toList()
        : null,
      _createdAt = json['createdAt'] != null ? TemporalDateTime.fromString(json['createdAt']) : null,
      _updatedAt = json['updatedAt'] != null ? TemporalDateTime.fromString(json['updatedAt']) : null;
  
  ...
}
```

I want to create an extension class `GaitPatient`. But, I am running into this error,

> The unnamed constructor of superclass 'Patient' (called by the default constructor of 'GaitPatient') must be a generative constructor, but factory found. Try adding an explicit constructor that has a different superinitializer or changing the superclass constructor 'Patient Patient(...)' to not be a factory constructor

I am currently looking at using `Patient.fromJSON` constructor, but a bit hesitant about using that because it doesn't seem to be the cleanest... what are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

```html
@immutable
class GaitPatient extends Patient {
  final double? gaitSpeed;
  
  const GaitPatient._internal({
    required String id, 
    required String name, 
    required String family_name, 
    required TemporalDate dob, 
    required Gender gender, 
    required double height_in_inches, 
    List<Assessment>? Assessments, 
    TemporalDateTime? createdAt, 
    TemporalDateTime? updatedAt, 
    this.gaitSpeed
  }) : super._internal(
    id: id, 
    name: name, 
    family_name: family_name, 
    dob: dob, 
    gender: gender, 
    height_in_inches: height_in_inches, 
    Assessments: Assessments, 
    createdAt: createdAt, 
    updatedAt: updatedAt
  );

  factory GaitPatient({
    String? id,
    required String name,
    required String family_name,
    required TemporalDate dob,
    required Gender gender,
    required double height_in_inches,
    List<Assessment>? Assessments,
    TemporalDateTime? createdAt,
    TemporalDateTime? updatedAt,
    double? gaitSpeed
  }) {
    return GaitPatient._internal(
      id: id ?? UUID.getUUID(),
      name: name,
      family_name: family_name,
      dob: dob,
      gender: gender,
      height_in_inches: height_in_inches,
      Assessments: Assessments,
      createdAt: createdAt,
      updatedAt: updatedAt,
      gaitSpeed: gaitSpeed
    );
  }

  GaitPatient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) 
    : gaitSpeed = json['gaitSpeed'],
      super.fromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    ...super.toJson(),
    'gaitSpeed': gaitSpeed,
  };
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided, I can see that Patient is a class that extends Model and has several fields. The class has a factory constructor and a private constructor. The factory constructor allows you to create a new instance of Patient using named parameters, while the private constructor is used internally to create a new instance of Patient with required parameters.

To create a subclass of Patient, you can use the extends keyword followed by the name of the superclass. Here is an example of how you can define a subclass GaitPatient that extends Patient:

Comment: I appreciate the answer, unfortunately, I tried this one out before and got this error:
`The class 'Patient' doesn't have a constructor named '_internal'.
Try defining a constructor named '_internal' in 'Patient', or invoking a different constructor.`
Is it possible that the Amplify team didn't want their Model classes to be extended?